How to Change Audio Speed Without Affecting Pitch and Vice Versa in Java?
I am working on an audio processing application in Java, and I need to implement the following functionality:
Change the playback speed without affecting the pitch of the audio.
Change the pitch without affecting the speed of the audio.
I understand that this is achievable through DSP (Digital Signal Processing) techniques, but I want to implement this directly in Java without relying on external libraries like SoundTouch.
What would be the most effective way to approach this problem in Java? I am open to suggestions using Java's audio libraries (javax.sound.sampled, etc.) or other DSP algorithms. Are there any specific techniques (e.g., time-stretching, phase vocoding) that can be implemented in Java to achieve these effects?
What Have I Tried:

I’ve been experimenting with javax.sound.sampled for basic audio processing. I can successfully change the speed by manipulating the playback rate, but this also changes the pitch, which I want to avoid.
I’ve read about algorithms like time-stretching (which allows speed changes without affecting pitch) and phase vocoding (which allows pitch changes without affecting speed), but I haven't found a clear Java implementation.
I've tried adjusting the sample rate directly, but it does not achieve the desired effect of independent speed and pitch control.

What Was I Expecting:

I was hoping that manipulating the audio sample rate or buffer size could allow control over speed and pitch independently. However, I realized this approach causes both pitch and speed to change together.
I’m expecting to implement algorithms or techniques like PSOLA  or phase vocoding in Java to handle pitch-shifting and time-stretching separately.


Some of this might be covered on the [dsp.se] or [sound.se] sites, for example  this question
